# Paypal API for checking status of recurring (subscription) payment

Tags: php, api, paypal

Does anyone know is there any way to check status of recurring (subscription) payment at PayPal.
I just want to submit transaction ID and to see is payment canceled (suspended) or it is still active.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the Recurring Payments API you can use [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) to obtain details including the current status of the profile.

If you're working with Standard Subscriptions, though, then there is no API to obtain the details, unfortunately.

In either case, I'd recommend looking into [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  Using it you could automate the process of sending email notifications, updating your own database, etc. when new profiles are created, suspended, re-activated, etc.

Comment: But I need to see recurring profile by providing transaction ID. Is that possible at all??

Comment: You can use GetTransactionDetails to obtain the profile ID using the transaction ID, and then use GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails to obtain the profile details.